# Puphpet - Adding custom files to hiera.yaml

Tags: vagrant, puphpet, hiera

I asked for this question on the github repo but no one answered me :/ (see [this topic](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2585))

Here is my original question :

> I would like to customize the hiera.yaml, adding new conf files to the ":hierarchy:" section.
>   But it seems it doesn't work when I do a "vagrant up" :/
>
> Do I have to destroy and re-up my vagrant box ?
>
> The reason why I want to add custom files to hiera.yaml is that I have multiple boxes and I would like to define my vhosts, sql databases and users, etc... for all of them at once.

Anyone has a solution to my problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you already built the VM, provisioning is not run on following `vagrant up` (only the initial one will run the provisioning)

If you need to force a provisioning after you change the `hiera.yaml` file is to run

```
$ vagrant provision
```

or

```
$ vagrant up --provision
```

Comment: Hi Frédéric,

I've already done the following commands  : "vagrant up", "vagrant provision" and "vagrant up --provision" but that does not change a thing :/